# ASP.NET Identity redirect to full URL after login

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a Blazor website (**IdentityApp**) that includes scaffolded ASP.NET identity integration. That website is processing logins and setting a shared cookie that my other `localhost` Blazor application (**LogicApp**) can see.

When I access **LogicApp** (`https://localhost:9876`), I check the context for a recognised user (using the shared cookie) and then manually redirect *anonymous* users to the scaffolded **IdentityApp** login page: `https://localhost:1234/identity/account/login`.

I also pass through the fully encoded URL of **LogicApp** home page  in the `returnUrl`, for example; `https://localhost:1234/identity/account/login?returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2F`

The login process is working OK (the shared cookie is set correctly), but then I get an exception;

> InvalidOperationException: The supplied URL is not local. A URL with an absolute path is considered local if it does not have a host/authority part. URLs using virtual paths ('~/') are also local.

Within ASP.NET Identity (.NET Core 3.1);

- How can I configure **IdentityApp** to allow full urls within `returnUrl`?
  or,
- How can I override the scaffolded *Login* logic to take control of the redirect and use my `returnUrl` value?

Answer (score 0):

So I found an answer to my own problem (but still interested to hear of alternative solutions)..

Within the scaffolded pages locate `Login.cshtml.cs` and replace the reference to `LocalRedirect(...)` in in the `OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)` method, for example;

```
...
if (result.Succeeded)
{
   _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
   //return LocalRedirect(returnUrl); // remove this. 
   return Redirect(returnUrl); //TODO: define a list of acceptable return Urls (localhost / yourdomain.com etc)
}
...
```

You may also need to do this in Login2FA.cshtml.cs as well as other places that deal with this `ReturnUrl` value.

NOTE: `LocalRedirect` is used to prevent malicious redirects occurring so it would be wise to also add some logic to check the returnUrls that have been passed in.